Current sensing in DC-DC converter
I studied DC-DC converter in peak/valley/average mode control and I have a question about the methodology to sense the current in average current mode control. I saw lot of paper about DCR sensing but after studied it , I saw that the accuracy with this methodology is very poor due to the sensing pin and also due to the fact it's impossible to perfectly match the time constant RC and L/R. Is there any other better and very accurate method to sense a current through an inductor ? The purpose will be to be able to sense for example in buck and boost at the same time that's why I would like to find an accurate methodology to directly sense on the inductor.
